# Spinning up VM from Powershell with multiple admins

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a script which spins up an Azure VM and specifies an admin username and password.

Is it possible to have the script setup a second admin? The reason for this is so that more than one user can be on the machine at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the vm with `Invoke-Command`?
If yes, might this helps: [How to Manage Local Users and Groups using PowerShell](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ITOps-Talk-Blog/How-to-Manage-Local-Users-and-Groups-using-PowerShell/ba-p/733544)

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, two users can access Azure windows VM concurrently. A maximum of two concurrent connections are supported unless the server is configured as a [Remote Desktop Services](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2013/09/19/step-by-step-remote-desktop-services-on-windows-azure-a-cost-effective-alternative-to-desktop-as-a-service-part-2/) session host. Regarding how to add local user to Azure VM, you use the the VM Access extension in Azure PowerShell. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/reset-rdp?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json#reset-by-using-the-vmaccess-extension-and-powershell) 
[image]
For example

```
Connect-AzAccount 

$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName jimtest -Name jimtest

$name = "jimtest1"
$password = "Pass***!"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($name, $secpasswd)
Set-AzVMAccessExtension -Credential $mycred -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -VMName $vm.Name -Location $vm.Location -Name VMAccessAgent -TypeHandlerVersion "2.0"
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this PowerShell command below to add an admin account to your VM :

```
$adminName = "testadmin"
$passstr = "password123!"
$Password =  ConvertTo-SecureString -String $passstr -AsPlainText -Force
New-LocalUser $adminName -Password $Password -FullName $adminName -Description "test admin account"
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $adminName
```

And you can use the Powershell command below to run your custom Powershell command on your Azure VMs(get started with azure powershell [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-2.8.0)):

```
Connect-AzAccount
$vm = Get-AzVM -Name "<your vm name>" -ResourceGroupName "<your vm resource group>"
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -VM $vm  -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath "<path of adding admin account command>"
```

so just save the first part command as a .ps1 file , and copy the path as value of   you can add an local admin account to your VM.

Result : 
[image]